# Why are Promises not "awaited" by default?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous-programming, async, typescript, promises

In the latest version of languages like TypeScript or ECMAScript you can use `async`/`await` constructs to write code that combines the clean structure of synchronous programming with the performance advantages of asynchronous code.

Take this as an example:

```
async function isAdmin() {
    // Async IO request...
    return false;
}

async function doSomething() {
    if (await isAdmin()) {
        console.log("Done");
    } else throw new Error("Unauthorized");
}

doSomething();
```

It looks very clean. However, because of the synchronous look of the code it's not that difficult to forget to `await` on some function invocation, thus writing things like this:

```
// ...
if (isAdmin()) {
    console.log("Done");
} else throw new Error("Unauthorized");
```

which is dangerously wrong.

**What's the rationale behind this choice, instead of awaiting all async functions by default and letting the programmer choose which operation to do asynchronously?** Something like this made-up syntax:

```
var admin = isAdmin(); // wait isAdmin to return a result
async doSomething();   // call doSomething asynchronously
doSomething();         // call doSomething synchronously
var promise = async doSomething(); // Get the underlying Promise
```

Comment: Related: [Why do we need the async keyword?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/187492/1204)

Comment: What makes your example dangerously wrong is javascript's weak typing that allows you to treat a promise like a boolean.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: It works similarly in C# as well.  A promise is returned, but because it has `await` in front of it, you can treat it as if it is returning the actual promised value.

Comment: @CodesInChaos True, but even with stronger typing we would get the same issue by handling exceptions of async methods.
Btw, thanks for your answer, clear and right to the point :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey - `if (isAdmin())` will not compile in C# since you can't evaluate a `Task` in a boolean context.

Comment: @Lee True; without the `await`, you would have to say `isAdmin().Value`

Comment: These answers are surprising; I thought it was entirely for historical reasons, to maintain backward compatibility, not because anybody thought it was a good design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that a function being `async` doesn't turn it into something completely different, it just enables some syntax. A normal function returning a promise is just as asynchronous as a function marked with `async`.

1. The `await` serves as a warning sign "the world may have changed in the mean time".

   `await` may be easier than multi threading, but it's still *very* error prone. During code review you have to look at each `await`, thinking "does the function rely on any information obtained before the `await` still being the same? Is this guaranteed?". Without an explicit `await`, you have to do so at every function invocation.
2. Backwards compatibility. With your proposal code behaves completely different if the browse/runtime supports awaiting or not.
3. If your code doesn't want to deal with awaiting, it needs to insert an `async` at every call to an externally defined function, just in case it returns a promise.
4. Performance. The runtime needs to insert an `if result is a promise then await` check at every method call.

Answer (score 1):

**Because you may not want to await all of your functions.**  You might want some of them to run synchronously.

Your example is not "dangerously wrong," it's merely synchronous.

By the way, you shouldn't have to `await` a function named `isAdmin()`; it should return almost immediately anyway, and since the `if` statement needs the return result before it can proceed, it's probably not even going to run asynchronously.

As to why two keywords are used instead of one, it's explained in the [TypeScript proposal for Async Dunctions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1664):

> An Async Function is a JavaScript Function, Parameterized Arrow
>   Function, Method, or Get Accessor that has been prefixed with the
>   `async` modifier. This modifier informs the compiler that function
>   body transposition is required, and that the keyword `await` should be
>   treated as a unary expression instead of an identifier.

Comment: The isAdmin function was an example; suppose it needs to check the database.
In addition, I think you missed the last example in my question, where I show a potential alternative way to run function asynchronously :)

Comment: Well, the `async` `await` model originates from C#.  In C#, the `async` keyword signals the compiler that the method so marked has `async` semantics.  But you still have to `await` a method within that `async` method to make it asynchronous, otherwise the `async` keyword is a big, fat no-op.  Without the `async` keyword you'll get a compiler error when you try to `await`.

Comment: The reasons why C# did it this way are described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/11/11/asynchrony-in-c-5-part-six-whither-async/).  I assume TypeScript did it the same way because C# and TypeScript are both Microsoft products.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of my question. What I'm asking is: why do I have to explicitly await asynchronous functions, instead of implicitly await them and explicitly call them asynchronously?

Comment: How is the method going to know it is asynchronous if you don't put `await` in front of it?

Comment: Because of a different language syntax and semantic.

Comment: Is your issue that there are two keywords, and not just one?  Asynchronicity by default doesn't sound like a good design choice to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43757/discussion-between-robert-harvey-and-danieleds).